# error 13 error C2011: 'ConnectionInfo' : 'struct' type redefinition

Tags: c++

The error I get is: error 13 error C2011: 'ConnectionInfo' : 'struct' type redefinition \src\server\authserver\server\RealmSocket.h 33

Basicly i got this from someone, and i cant contact him anymore, i want to make it work.

After i did what Jonas told me to, i still get this : 'ConnectionInfo' : undeclared identifier \src\server\game\Server\WorldSocket.h 54

Im not sure if 
    --- a/src/server/authserver/Server/RealmSocket.cpp
    +++ b/src/server/authserver/Server/RealmSocket.cpp

means i should delete the a/src/server/authserver/Server/RealmSocket.cpp from there.

```
diff --git a/src/server/authserver/Server/RealmSocket.cpp b/src/server/authserver    /Server/RealmSocket.cpp
index 6710a6a..0d2a854 100644
--- a/src/server/authserver/Server/RealmSocket.cpp
+++ b/src/server/authserver/Server/RealmSocket.cpp
@@ -23,6 +23,8 @@


@@ -64,6 +70,17 @@ int RealmSocket::open(void * arg)
 _remoteAddress = addr.get_host_addr();
 _remotePort = addr.get_port_number();

+   time_t currentTime = time(NULL);
+
+   AntiConnectionFloodMap::iterator itr = activeConnections.find(_remoteAddress);
+   if (itr != activeConnections.end())
+   {
+       if (currentTime <= itr->second.lastConnectionTime +     MAX_CONNECTION_WAIT_TIME || ++itr->second.connectionAmount == MAX_CONNECTION_PER_IP)
+           return -1;
+
+           itr->second.lastConnectionTime  = currentTime;
```

Comment: After i deleted once i get this'ConnectionInfo' : undeclared identifier \src\server\game\Server\WorldSocket.h 54

Answer (score 2):

This is defined twice in the code. Remove one of them.

```
struct ConnectionInfo

{
ConnectionInfo(time_t currentTime) : lastConnectionTime(currentTime), connectionAmount(1) {}
time_t lastConnectionTime;
uint16 connectionAmount;

};
```

Comment: After i deleted once i get this'ConnectionInfo' : undeclared identifier \src\server\game\Server\WorldSocket.h 54

Comment: No, you need to delete the one in realmsocket.h on line 33.. just like it says in the error message.